# AS3 - adding eventListener to inherited property from inside and outside of the class

Tags: actionscript-3, events, inheritance

Reading a book i stumbled on this example:

Here is the class:

```
package com.learningactionscript3.loading {

import flash.display.Loader;
import flash.display.LoaderInfo;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.events.HTTPStatusEvent;
import flash.events.IOErrorEvent;
import flash.events.ProgressEvent;
import flash.net.URLRequest;

public class CustomLoader extends Loader {

    private var _ldrInfo:LoaderInfo;
    private var _path:String;
    private var _verbose:Boolean = false;
    private var _loadedPercent:Number = 0;
    //constructor
    public function CustomLoader(path:String="", 
                                 verbose:Boolean=false) {
        _path = path;
        _verbose = verbose;

        addListeners();

        if (path != null) {
            try {
                this.load(new URLRequest(path));
            } catch (err:Error) {
                trace("Cannot load", _path, err.message);
            }
        }
    }
    //listeners
    private function addListeners():void {
        _ldrInfo = this.contentLoaderInfo;
        _ldrInfo.addEventListener(Event.OPEN,
                                  onOpen, false, 0, true);
        _ldrInfo.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS,
                                  onProgress, false, 0, true);
        _ldrInfo.addEventListener(HTTPStatusEvent.HTTP_STATUS,
                                  onStatusEvent, 
                                  false, 0, true);
        _ldrInfo.addEventListener(Event.INIT,
                                  onInit, false, 0, true);
        _ldrInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE,
                                  onComplete, false, 0, true);
        _ldrInfo.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR,
                                  onIOError, false, 0, true);
        _ldrInfo.addEventListener(Event.UNLOAD,
                                  onUnloadContent, 
                                  false, 0, true);
    }

    public function removeListeners():void {
        _ldrInfo.removeEventListener(Event.OPEN, onOpen);
        _ldrInfo.removeEventListener(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS,
                                     onProgress);
        _ldrInfo.removeEventListener(HTTPStatusEvent.HTTP_STATUS,
                                     onStatusEvent);
        _ldrInfo.removeEventListener(Event.INIT, onInit);
        _ldrInfo.removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, 
                                     onComplete);
        _ldrInfo.removeEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, 
                                     onIOError);
        _ldrInfo.removeEventListener(Event.UNLOAD, 
                                     onUnloadContent);
    }
    //listener methods, getter, and setter
    private function onOpen(evt:Event):void {
        if (_verbose) { trace("Loading begun:", _path); }
    }

    private function onProgress(evt:ProgressEvent):void {
        _loadedPercent = evt.bytesLoaded/evt.bytesTotal;

        if (_verbose) { 
            trace("Loading", _path, 
                  "-- progress (0-1):", _loadedPercent);
        }
    }

    private function onStatusEvent(evt:HTTPStatusEvent):void {
        if (_verbose) { trace("HTTP status:", evt.status); }
    }

    private function onInit(evt:Event):void {
        if (_verbose) { 
            trace("Content initialized. Properties:"); 
            trace("  url:", evt.target.url)
            trace("  Same Domain:", evt.target.sameDomain)
            if (evt.target.contentType == 
                "application/x-shockwave-flash") {
                trace("  SWF Version:", evt.target.swfVersion)
                trace("  AS Version:", 
                      evt.target.actionScriptVersion)
                trace("  Frame Rate:", evt.target.frameRate)
            }
        }
    }

    private function onComplete(evt:Event):void {
        if (_verbose) { trace("Loading complete:", _path); }
    }

    private function onUnloadContent(evt:Event):void {
        if (_verbose) { trace("Unloaded:", _path); }
    }

    private function onIOError(evt:IOErrorEvent):void {
        trace("Loading error:\n", evt.text);
    }

    public function get percentLoaded():Number {
        return _loadedPercent;
    }

    public function set verbose(bool:Boolean):void {
        _verbose = bool;
    }
}
```

}

the problem is in this line:

```
_ldrInfo = this.contentLoaderInfo;
```

A few of event Listeners is added internally to this property...and now it's ok.

Now in the frame of FLA file (where this class is instantiated) and a new eventListener, with the same name of the one, created internally is added:

var swfLoader:CustomLoader = new CustomLoader("swfToLoad.swf", true);
addChild(swfLoader);

swfLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, 
                                             onComplete,
                                             false, 0, true);

What I deduce from this example is that the swfLoader.contentLoaderInfo and  _ldrInfo = this.contentLoaderInfo refer to the same object in the same memory location. So you may think: "well the last added event will overwrite the first one (the internally one added). But it doesn't. The two event listeners will respond sequentially. First the internal listener and then the external listener. How It's possible?

Answer (score 2):

Why not? You can add as many listeners as you want for one event type. They do not override each other. To remove the listener, use [removeEventListener](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/EventDispatcher.html#removeEventListener%28%29) method. To manage the calling sequence use `priority` parameter.

```
public function addEventListener(type:String, listener:Function, useCapture:Boolean = false, priority:int = 0, useWeakReference:Boolean = false):void
```

*priority:int (default = 0) — The priority level of the event listener. The priority is designated by a signed 32-bit integer. The higher the number, the higher the priority. All listeners with priority n are processed before listeners of priority n-1. If two or more listeners share the same priority, they are processed in the order in which they were added. The default priority is 0.*

Comment: With the same name callback funtion too? Moreover a note in the book says:
"The event listeners in the example FLA
files are not the same as the event listeners
inside the class. All the internal
listeners are at the class level, and are
private so nothing outside the class is
aware of their existence. The listeners
in the example FLA files are applied to
class instances."

Aren't swfLoader.contentLoaderInfo and _ldrInfo the same object?

Comment: @cubob, they are the same instance. That's why no differ, where you add listeners.